# Winphone 10 newbie question

Tags: windows-10-mobile, lumia-650

Very happy with my Lumia 735 running Windows Phone 8.1, so I bought a Lumia 650 for my wife, but some things are bugging me about Windows 10 Mobile.

Anything that I 'back' out of seems to stay alive, even settings. Of course "apps don't cost anything when they lose focus", but when you're 'alt-tabbing' between two apps, it's painful if you have 10 others open.

Is this 'normal'? Is there an option to say "back means kill; if I'm not finished I'll hit Start"?

Comment: Use the "Feedback Hub" app to let Microsoft know that you'd like an option to control when apps get closed.

Comment: Presumably, you're aware you can close open apps by long-pressing the "Back" button, then hitting the "X" for open apps.

Comment: @MaxVernon, yes, and being a bit OCD, I find myself doing that a *lot* :)

Answer (score 3):

No. There is no such option. Apps will remain in the app switcher unless it exceeds the limit or you manually close.

Comment: But this is different to Windows Phone 8.1, right?

Comment: @Benjol Yes a bit. But the change is not in OS. In Windows 10 all UWP apps remain in background it seems. Apps such as White Screen of Life, Gestulator, Xender, etc... goes out of background when hitting back button and remains in background when hitting Windows key. This is happening in Windows 10. But **all apps that is built for Windows 10 remain in background regardless of that**. So in future it will be like that only.

Comment: Ugh, I'm starting to regret buying this phone. Shame I can't downgrade it to 8.1 :(